# Is there any way to use metal performance shader on the docker container?

Tags: docker, metal-performance-shaders

I'm currently using mac book m2 pro and installed Docker desktop to create an development container on linux.
I know there is a `--gpus` option in `docker run` to add gpu to the container when starting the container. But is there any way to use the MPS on the mac book on the docker container?
I think this may never work... and this question may sound stupid, but I couldn't find any article pointing this.
Thank you

- Searched google
- Searched the official docker page